# Can anyone help me with jQuery selectors please?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select `class="item"` as draggable but this selector is not working:

```
<body>
 <div id="contentwrapper">
  <div id="contentcolumn">
   <div class="innertube" >
    <ul class="products">
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="item">   // i want to select this
      <img src="images/shirt1.gif"/>
      <div>
       <p>Balloon</p>
       <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
     </a><!-- more products like this --></li></ul></div></div></div>
<script>
$('.item').draggable(....)    // not working
</scipt>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is there an element with that class in the markup?

Comment: If you're going to do anything with Javascript and JQuery, you need to use Firefox with Firebug and FireQuery.

Comment: @PaulTomblin - Or Chrome Console... (And I'm a big Firebug fan, but c'mon...)

Comment: Yikes - several unclosed tags in there (ul, li)! Edit: bah, the close tags are hiding, apologies. Nevertheless, where you get jQuery problems, sometimes it pays to check for XHTML validity :)

Comment: Are you sure it's the selector that's not working? Did you try other selectors? We don't see your entire code. There could be a number of reasons why this wouldn't work. Maybe you haven't included jQuery UI? (Remember that draggable is not part of the basic jQuery.)

Comment: Chrome Console isn't anywhere near as Firefox and FireQuery.  FireQuery shows you all the JQuery data stored in the DOM, all the callbacks, etc.

Comment: @PaulTomblin - Not sure how I missed FireQuery, I'll have to check that out. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

remove the wrong    `</scipt>` ..........

Answer (score 1):

The jquery code seems to be correct. maybe it works better if you do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').draggable(....)
});
```

this way it wont try to find the  tags before the complete DOM is loaded.

Comment: If the call to `.item` comes after the `.item` elements, there won't be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

1) < script language=...>

2) put all this stuff into document.ready() callback description.